# PHP strpos dont works properly(Path Generator)

Tags: php, strpos

I wanted to create a function that generates an image path from an array.The function has one argument and that argument is for you to decide from which folder you want to choose images.
So I have 90 elements in an array and each element is a path.Now I don't want a .png image so I wanted to create something like this(but it didn't work for me):

```
public function getRandomPath($RoboticOrArenag)
{
    if ($RoboticOrArenag == 'Robotic' || $RoboticOrArenag == 'robotic') {
        $countofarray = count($this->allImagesRobotic);
    } else if ($RoboticOrArenag == 'Arenag' || $RoboticOrArenag == 'arenag') {
        $countofarray = count($this->allImagesArenag);
    } else {
        $RoboticOrArenag = 0;
    }
        $randomNumber = rand(0, $countofarray);
    if ($RoboticOrArenag == 'Robotic' || $RoboticOrArenag == 'robotic') {
        if($randomNumber==50){
            $randomNumber--;
        }
        else if ($randomNumber==0){
            $randomNumber++;
        }
        $randomNumberPath = $this->allImagesRobotic[$randomNumber];
    } else if ($RoboticOrArenag == 'Arenag' || $RoboticOrArenag == 'arenag') {
        if($randomNumber==33){
            $randomNumber--;
        }
        else if ($randomNumber==0){
            $randomNumber++;
        }
        $randomNumberPath = $this->allImagesArenag[$randomNumber];
        while(strpos($randomNumberPath, '.png') == true){
            $randomNumber = rand(0, $countofarray);
            $randomNumberPath = $this->allImagesArenag[$randomNumber];
        }
    } else {
        $randomNumberPath = 0;
    }
    $randomPath = "/img/$RoboticOrArenag/$randomNumberPath";
    return $randomPath;
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Try to add which result you get and what you expect. One thing i can see it that it seems like you only check for .png if it is 'Arenag' and then add it if it is, not if it isn't.

Comment: Wow, you actually solve the problem with your question :D Thanks.I wanted to disable all .png images.But accidently I put the while loop into 'Arenag'.So it checks the .png images only for 'Arenag' folder.Anyways the .png images were in a folder called 'robotic' so it didn't checked in that folder because I put the while loop in 'Arenag'.Did you understand what did I wanted ? :D (Sorry for my bad English) And thanks a lot of :)